# SQL output convert columns to rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the following SQL query:

```
select distinct col + "abc" value1, col+ "xyz" value2
from table_name
where col = "1234567890"
```

This returns output as:

```
value1        value2
1234567890abc 1234567890xyz
```

But I want the output as:

```
value
1234567890abc
1234567890xyz
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `union all`

```
select distinct col + "abc" value
from table_name
where col = "1234567890"
union all
select distinct col+ "xyz" 
from table_name
where col = "1234567890"
```

Comment: You accepted the answer, but why someone downvoted me? that's a question :)

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but I just upvoted your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use concat and union all

```
select concat(col, 'abc') value1
from table_name
where col = '1234567890'
union all
select concat(col, 'xyz')
from table_name
where col = '1234567890'
```